# How to remove html tags getting from sqlite database in android?

Tags: android

In my project I am getting data from **sqlite database** and setting that data to my **textviews**. But the **data which I am getting contains html tags** which is looking odd when I am displaying. Can **we remove those html tags** after getting them from database? Please help me regarding this.

Thanks in Advance.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use html tags instead to remove by following statement:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlString));
```

Comment: Hi in my app still it is displaying \r\n in the data...how can I remove that also? Please help me regarding this?

Comment: \r\n is not html character or keyword, you need to replace these character by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Download the JSoup library from http://jsoup.org/, and use it this way:

```
Jsoup.parse(html).text();
```

This will return a String that you can put in your textview.